# Python: Removing random whitespace from a string of numbers

Tags: python, trim, removing-whitespace

Tried a different number of combinations, none to avail.

Basically this is the string of numbers that I have:

> ```
> 20101002  100224   1    1044      45508  1001  1002  1003  1004  1005  1006
> ```

Output I'm after:

```
20101002 100224 1 1044 45508 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006
```

Basically all whitespace before and after the last number have to be trimmed. On top of that there should only be one whitespace between the numbers.

I should add that the code I currently have is as follows and only deals with the whitespace at the start and end of the string:

```
row = line.strip().split(' ')
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: use a _regex_ and `re.sub()` method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this

```
s = '20101002  100224   1    1044      45508  1001  1002  1003  1004  1005  1006'
new_s = ' '.join(s.split())
print(new_s)
```

produces

```
20101002 100224 1 1044 45508 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006
```

Basically, there are two steps involved:

first we split the string into words with `s.split()`, which returns this list

```
['20101002', '100224', '1', '1044', '45508', '1001', '1002', '1003', '1004', '1005', '1006']
```

then we pass the list to `' '.join`, which joins all the elements of the list using the space character between them

Comment: I get ` , , , ,2,0,1,0,1,0,0,2, , ,1,0,0,2,2,4, , , ,1, , , , ,1,0,4,4, , , , , , ,4,5,5,0,8, , ,1,0,0,1, , ,1,0,0,2, , ,1,0,0,3, , ,1,0,0,4, , ,1,0,0,5, , ,1,0,0,6,"
"` back. Could it be because I'm using Python 3?

Comment: I have tried the code on python 3.4.3 and it works fine. Copy and paste it

Comment: it looks good when I print it on terminal but it changes format when I export it to a csv :/ `with open(bad_csv_file, 'w') as myfile:
      wr = csv.writer(myfile)
      for line in bad_csv:
        row = ' '.join(line.split())
        print(row)
        wr.writerow(row)` Any ideas why?

Comment: maybe it's because the `for` loop is iterating over `bad_csv` instead of `myfile`?

Comment: `fname = "track_param_stoch.txt"
bad_csv_file = 'bad_hist_csv.csv'
bad_csv = [] 
with open(fname) as f:
      lines = f.readlines()
  for line in lines:
      good_csv.append(line) if pattern.match(line) else bad_csv.append(line)`
it's iterating correctly, guess this is a output to csv problem not a strip whitespace one :/

Comment: I have never used the csv module yet. I have answered your question regarding the string. Please post a new question in case the subject changes.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
text = "20101002  100224   1    1044      45508  1001  1002  1003  1004  1005  1006"
re.sub(r"\s+", " ", text)
#=> 20101002 100224 1 1044 45508 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Python's `str.split` method splits on whitespace.

```
a = "20101002  100224   1    1044      45508  1001  1002  1003  1004  1005  1006"

" ".join(a.split())
```